# Check when all Ajax Requests are complete - Pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, request

I know about [jQuery's ajaxStop](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) method.

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() { //Do something });
```

Is there a way to do this with pure JavaScript if jQuery is not available?

Could you provide an example if so?

Cheers

Comment: You could have a look in the jQuery sources, how it is handled there ...

Comment: Yes, you can do this without jQuery... It's not even that hard. Was that the question? Or did you expect us to show you how?

Comment: Could you let me know how? That was the question indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very well, I'll bite (though not even trying is quite lazy on your part):

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstop/):

> Whenever an Ajax request completes, jQuery checks whether there are any other outstanding Ajax requests. If none remain, jQuery triggers the ajaxStop event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the .ajaxStop() method are executed at this time.

So what will you need? Well: a central API (a module of sorts) that you'll use to perform AJAX requests. In this module, you'll have to keep track of pending requests, and remove them once the requests have terminated.
If the queue (so to speak) is empty, then you can check the `ajaxStop` queue for any registered callbacks, and invoke those.

A basic setup (pseudo-code) would look like this:

```
var myAjax = (function()
{//create closure scope to track ajax requests
    var activeRequests = [],
        stopQueue = [],
        ajaxModule = {},//the module itself
        createXhr = function(){};//function to create XHR requests
    ajaxModule.ajax = function(params, callback)
    {
        var xhr = createXhr(params),
            key = activeRequests.length;
        activeRequests.push(xhr);//add to active array
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
        {//assign internal handler
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)
            {
                //invoke passed callback only if request is done
                callback.call(this, []);//pass params as you please
                activeRequests.filter(function(e)
                {
                     return e !== this;
                }, this);//define this callback in closure, of course
                if (activeRequests.length === 0)
                {//no more active requests
                    stopQueue.map(function(callback)
                    {
                        callback();//invoke callbacks
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    };
    return ajaxModule;//expose module
}());
```

Of course, you'll still have to implement the functions that manage the stopQueue callbacks, and you'll have to implement a reliable AJAX module yourself, but this is the simple setup that you could use.

Answer (score 0):

javascript `abort();` method
for reference
http://help.dottoro.com/ljomfaxv.php

```
var httpRequest = null;
function sentReq() {
            if (!httpRequest) {
                httpRequest = CreateHTTPRequestObject ();   
            }
            if (httpRequest) {          

                var url = "file.php";

                httpRequest.open ("GET", url, true);  
                httpRequest.onreadystatechange = OnStateChange;
                httpRequest.send (null);
}

function abort(){
  if(httpRequest)
      httpRequest.abort();
}
```

Comment: It would help it you included a short example.